# Ransack needs <Model> Associations explicitly allowlisted as searchable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ransack

### Background

My code was running and working until I installed the gem 'ipaddress' but now my previous created models now all get the following error

Ransack needs <MODEL_NAME> associations explicitly allowlisted as
searchable.

Define a `ransackable_associations` class method in your `User`
model, watching out for items you DON'T want searchable (for
example, `encrypted_password`, `password_reset_token`, `owner` or
other sensitive information). You can use the following as a base:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # ...

  def self.ransackable_associations(auth_object = nil)
    ["comments", "created_by", "favorites", "impressions_by_user", "updated_by", "user_group"]
  end

  # ...

The issue I have with this is I need a dynamic to do this instead of having to redo this for every single model that I have created.
```

Comment: Try this..
https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/going-further/other-notes/#authorization-allowlistingdenylisting

Comment: From reading the documentation I would have to do this for all controllers, I was hoping for a one time function

Comment: hmm..as the documentation says you just have to add it to ActiveRecord::Base..to get started. You have to change models only if you want to blacklist some of the columns of that model

Comment: I already have ActiveRecord::Base added to the models is the thing that leaves me a little confused

Answer (score 7):

### Solution

I had to change the models from using ActiveRecord::Base to using ApplicationRecord then create a Application_Record.rb file that contains the following code:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  primary_abstract_class

  Rails.logger.info("INSIDE APPLICATION RECORD");
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    column_names + _ransackers.keys
  end

  def self.ransackable_associations(auth_object = nil)
    reflect_on_all_associations.map { |a| a.name.to_s } + _ransackers.keys
  end
end
```

Then had to tweak the impressionist extension in the initializer to add the following method

```
def ransackable_associations(auth_object = nil)
  Rails.logger.info("WITHIN RANSACK ASSOCIATION")
  super + %w[impressionable]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with ransack 4, ransack requires explicit whitelisting for associations and attributes. This [merge request](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/1400) introduces the change.

If you know what you are doing, you can disable the behavior by reverting it to the pre-4.0 code.

```rb
# app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.ransackable_associations(auth_object = nil)
    @ransackable_associations ||= reflect_on_all_associations.map { |a| a.name.to_s }
  end

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    @ransackable_attributes ||= column_names + _ransackers.keys + _ransack_aliases.keys + attribute_aliases.keys
  end
end
```